# how to set interval-intraframes with omxh264enc element in gstreamer on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, omxplayer, usb-camera

I am using the omxh264enc to encode USB camera source on raspberry pi and stream the video, I would like to control the keyframe interval, but could not figure out how to, I currently
 using the following bash script :

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! 'video/x-raw, width=640 ,hight=480 ,framerate=30/1' ! videoconvert ! omxh264enc target-bitrate=400000 control-rate=variable ! fdsink
```

The idea is to mimic the raspivid function but with USB camera source instead

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Does the `omxh264enc` element has the `iframeinterval` property? I thought it did - or something very similar. However I believe OMX is just an API, the hardware may not fully support all features that are exposed.

Comment: no, it doesn't have iframeinterval property, I use version 1.0.0.1

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mitsuhito/ad3ae3e341726687457c <-- `interval-intraframes` and `periodicty-idr` sound promising..